# issue with writing to KML file using JavaAPIForKML

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipse-rcp, kml, jak

I was trying to generate KML file from a text file.
When I am trying to marshal the memory file, I am getting following exception.
Any clue?

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml$NameSpaceBeautyfier@1cfa4b2
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.createMarshaller(Kml.java:642)
    at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.marshal(Kml.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper` you need to ensure that you have the [**JAXB RI**](http://jaxb.java.net/) (or [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) on your class path.

The JDK contains a package renamed version of the JAXB RI so you could try the following property name instead:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html